# what plant/vine is this?

Tags: identification, houseplants, vines

What plant is this? Leaves are very small. How should I care for it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Syngonium podophyllum variety, common name Arrowhead vine - its usually kept as a houseplant, but in warmer countries, can be grown outdoors. It's relatively easy as a houseplant, but doesn't appreciate hot sunlight through a window - variegated versions like this one require brighter light than plain green varieties, but not direct sun, although a little winter sun isn't an issue. Water when the surface of the compost is just dry to the touch, water thoroughly, and tip away any water remaining in an outer pot or tray after 30 minutes. More info here http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/arrowhead-plant/arrowhead-plant-care-arrowhead-plant-or-syngonium-podophyllum.htm

Comment: but all the other arrowhead vines have bigger leaf. Or I missed something? If not, is this a dwarf version?

Comment: How long can it grow? Is it like Money Plant(devil's ivy)?

Comment: It's usually, as a houseplant contained in a pot, relatively small - I've never seen one develop climbing stems and different leaves,, but likely outdoors in appropriate climates it might get pretty tall, don't really know. Mine never get much bigger than about a foot high and wide at most